# Magento vs WooCommerce - what can Magento do that WooCommerce can't for a small to medium sized store?

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, woocommerce

I appreciate this is not the most original of questions although after quite a lot of searching I'm still yet to find anything that really answers my question convincingly. Essentially I'm looking to find out in what scenarios someone would benefit from using Magento over WooCommerce, assuming they are running a fairly typical store feature-wise with a couple of hundred products? This is also assuming that anything that can be fairly quickly / simply added functionality wise to WooCommerce via a plugin doesn't constitute an advantage for Magento.

Answer (score 2):

Please give us more details about your project in order to give you more appropriate answers.

Generally speaking..

Magento is an commerce platform.

WooCommerce is a plugin for Wordpress. Wordpress is a blog platform.

If you need a serious/stable/scalable e-commerce solution, you should choose Magento (or an other e-commerce platform).

**WooCommerce** is fine if you have a few products and no special requirements.

You can create a small eshop in a few hours, and you can customise it very easy without advanced development knowledge.

But, if you plan to have large catalogs and many orders you will get performance issues. 
Also, if you install plugins for features that are not supported by default, you should maintain and monitor all of them (You can not trust each individual developer. Anyone may stop supporting his extension any time, and in a wordpress/woocommerce update it may crash). In the end, it will NEVER even approach Magento's features.

On the other hand, **Magento** has much more settings (general settings for eshop, for products, categories etc.) to customise it and fit your needs perfectly.

- It supports more product types.
- You can integrate it with ERP.
- It supports multiple stores and store views in the same installation 
  (if you have many languages or different verticals) just out of the box.
- Statistics for orders/products/customers.
- Tax settings
- Better user management for administration purposes

plus much more you will discover day by day.

Nevertheless, The development cost is much higher and advanced programming skills are required.

**My personal opinion**, is that WooCommerce is for e-shops with small catalog (max 50 products) that have not special requirements and want to feel the market. 
If they succeed, they develop a Magento e-commerce solution. If they do not succeed, they have not lost much money and time.

I hope I helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  To give more context, I have a client thats looking to launch a fairly standard store (in that theres no requirements currently beyond the default offerings of WooCommerce) with around 150 products in its inventory. The client is a medium sized business with a good budget so cost here is not such a deciding factor although at the moment their favouring the Wordpress route for these reasons: Existing experience and familiarity with Wordpress - Opportunity to expand their current Wordpress website with ecomm functionality - Speed of design change implementation.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay, I did not get notified that your answered.

Comment: I would go with magento, you will have issues with this inventory. 
You will 'push' Wordpress and it could crash any time.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas. Your answer also helped me to decide for my project website which will have so many custom modifications, more than 200 products and it will be purely ecommerce website, no blog (for now). So I will choose Magento over Wordpress.